# php array combine problems

Tags: php, arrays, key

assume i have 4 arrays in php like these:

```
$a1 = array('a','b');
$a2 = array('1','2');
$b1 = array('a','c');
$b2 = array('3','4');
```

I want to make result like these:

```
$header = array('a','b','c');
$row1 = array('1','2',NULL);  //value from a2 where value from $a1 is same with $header
$row2 = array('3',NULL,'4');  //value from b2 where value from $b1 is same with $header
```

I can create `$header` by using `$header = array_unique(array_merge($a1,$b1));`
but how can I create row1 and row2??

Comment: Iterate over header fields and fill the new array with new values?

Comment: (edit: I figure out the pattern)

Comment: its based on $a1 and $b1.

Comment: `array_search()` is what you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$a1 = array('a','b');
$a2 = array('1','2');
$b1 = array('a','c');
$b2 = array('3','4');

$header = array_unique(array_merge($a1, $b1));

$advancedArrayCreator = function($header, $h, $d) {
    return array_map(function($column) use($h, $d) {
        $key = array_search($column, $h);
        if ($key !== false) {
            return $d[$key];
        }
    }, $header);
};

$row1 = $advancedArrayCreator($header, $a1, $a2);
$row2 = $advancedArrayCreator($header, $b1, $b2);

var_dump($row1, $row2);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/JkSl1i

Comment: *sidenote:* Anonymous functions is available at version 5.3.0+

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by combining some `array_*` functions

*(no loop, no anonymous functions)*

```
function create_row($header, $h, $d) {
  return array_values(array_merge(array_fill_keys($header, null), array_combine($h, $d)));
}

$a1 = array('a','b');
$a2 = array('1','2');
$b1 = array('a','c');
$b2 = array('3','4');

$header = array_unique(array_merge($a1, $b1));
$row1 = create_row($header, $a1, $a2);
$row2 = create_row($header, $b1, $b2);

var_dump($row1, $row2);
```

***[The demo](http://ideone.com/FbXxtZ)***

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach($header as $h)
    {
         if(array_search($h,$a1)===FALSE) {}   
         $row1[] = $a2[array_search($h,$a1)];
    }

    foreach($header as $h)
    {
            if(array_search($h,$b1)===FALSE) {}
            $row2[] = $b2[array_search($h,$b1)];
    }
```

Comment: the result was different with my objective Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 )

Comment: actually, it's fine, i'm just fixing a small glitch.. array_search is returning false, which is 0 so it's returning again, the 0'th index. i'll just post a fix

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$a1 = array('a','b');
$a2 = array('1','2');
$b1 = array('a','c');
$b2 = array('3','4');
$header = array_unique(array_merge($a1,$b1));
$row1 = array();    
foreach($header as $k => $v) {
  $result = array_search($v, $a1);
  if($result === FALSE) {
    $row1[$k] = null;
  } else {
    $row1[$k] = $a2[$k];
  }
}
var_dump($row1); // similar for $row2
```

which output:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Try this answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they miss an opportunity to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: @mickmackusa in 8.5 years it was opened 73 times, it's too specific to be helpful to anybody but the original question author.

Comment: Page visit count is more about the click-bait-iness of the title.  Researchers would know how niche this task is until after they load the page.

Answer (score 0):

Work around this:

```
$header = array_unique(array_merge($a1,$b1));

foreach ($header as $k => $v)
{
  $i = array_search($v, $a1);
  if (isset($i))
     $row1[$i] = $a2[$i];
  unset ($i);
  $i = array_search($v, $b1);
  if (isset($i))
    $row2[$i] = $b2[$i];
  unset ($i);   
}
```